# Passing parameters and filename?

Tags: windows, vb.net

I need to write a VB.Net Winform application that is called through Windows' context menu in Explorer and can take multiple parameters, where the final parameter is the full path to a file with spaces in it.

I tried the following as parameters, to no avail:

```
This is a test "%1" -> this
"This is a test "%1"" -> This is a test C:\Program
"This is a test" "%1" -> This is a test
"This is a test "%1%"" -> This is a test
```

Does someone know how to get Windows to pass the full path to the filename?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean as the value for `hkcr\filetype\shell\operation` ?

Comment: No, the last parameter is a filename, possibly with spaces in it. I can't get the source application to pass the whole string to my VB.Net application :-/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows is passing the full path. You're just having trouble parsing it.

```
This is a test "%1" -> This is a test "C:\Program Files\Blah blah"
-> cmdArgs(0) = "This"
-> cmdArgs(1) = "is"
-> cmdArgs(2) = "a"
-> cmdArgs(3) = "test"
-> cmdArgs(4) = "C:\Program Files\Blah blah"
```

In the above example, since there are no quotation marks around the words in the phrase "This is a test", they get passed as separate command line arguments.

```
"This is a test "%1"" -> "This is a test "C:\Program Files\Blah blah""
-> cmdArgs(0) = "This is a test "
-> cmdArgs(1) = "C:\Program"
-> cmdArgs(2) = "Files\Blah"
-> cmdArgs(3) = "blah"
```

In the second example, the quotation marks you inserted before the `%1` terminated the first argument, leaving the actual file name unquoted.

```
"This is a test" "%1" -> "This is a test" "C:\Program Files\Blah blah"
-> cmdArgs(0) = "This is a test"
-> cmdArgs(1) = "C:\Program Files\Blah blah"
```

In the third example, the two arguments are quoted separately, so they arrive cleanly as two arguments to your program. This is the one you should be using. Your problem is that you are looking only at `cmdArgs(0)` and ignoring the other stuff in the rest of `cmdArgs`. In particular, you forgot to check out `cmdArgs(1)`, which is where the filename is.

Comment: Thanks much Raymond. I thought all the parameters were sent as one string. Looping through My.Application.CommandLineArgs let me retrieve all of them.